# Retrieving itemAttachment from Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I receive emails (and attachments) from graph API. Some emails that come in have other messages attached (.msg), and those messages have attachments in them. Can anyone tell me how I could retrieve the attachments within the attachments.

I have tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentmessageid}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemAttachment/Item
```

but get error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid version",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2016-08-30T19:46:36"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myAccount/messages/{messageId}/attac
hments/{attachmentId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item
```

and the returned json has an `item` node with this value:

```
{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.message","id":"","createdDateTime":"2018-01-18T01:51:02Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2018-01-18T01:50:36Z",...
```

However, I would add that nested emails in that ItemAttachment are not extractable (or any attachment inside the nested email). I would like a method to treat an ItemAttachment as a FileAttachment to just download the bytes. I'll open another SO issue on that.